# One function that returns an array, or multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, performance

I came across this in some code I am reworking and am curious if there is any reason for doing it this way besides personal preference.  It seems unnecessarily obfuscated to me, considering how easy it would be to use several small functions with descriptive names. The purpose of the code is to validate a number of variables to ensure the data is properly formatted and within acceptable ranges while generating business data reports.  The report is mainly just a tool to bring attention to scheduling issues.

There is a single function that gets passed several values, runs a test on each one, then passes all the results back as a boolean array.

```
function testAll(test1, ..., test10) {
    var results = [false, ..., false];
    if (test1 condition == true) {
        results[0] = true;
    }
    ...
    if (test10 condition == true) {
        results[9] = true;
    }
    return results;
}
```

That function is then called and used like this.

```
var tblData = getCurrentData(); // function that gets database info through AJAX

for (i = 0; i < tblData.Rows.Count; i++) {

    // some code to append table element

    var results = testAll(strStartDate, ..., strTotalHours);
    if (results[0] == true) {
        $('#startDate' + i.toString()).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    ...
    if (results[9] == true) {
        $('#projectTime' + i.toString()).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
```

The original writer is gone and did not comment his code

Comment: Try posting the actual code, both approaches seem as wrong to me.

Comment: Code reuse. If the guy expected the function to be used in more than one place. This requires context, standalone it sure sounds silly.

Comment: Yeesh. This was pure laziness on the part of the original writer --- and not the good kind either. All I can recommend is start writing [Jasmine Unit Tests](http://jasmine.github.io/) for that function. Throw a bunch of input at it, and see what the results array is like. Then find all the places where this function is called and try to reverse engineer WTF the original author was trying to do.

Comment: Also, if you post the original code, it might be a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not technically address the question I posed, it is the solution to cleaning up the code in this case.

After further review it made more sense to use a non value returning function that performs the css formatting because of how simple the the tasks after evaluation are.

-Modified function

```
function verifyData(startDate, ..., timeSpent) {
    if (startDate isValid != true) {
        $('#startDate' + i.toString()).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    ...
    if (timeSpent isValid != true) {
        $('#projectTime' + i.toString()).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
```

-New method of calling and using

```
var tblData = getCurrentData(); // function that gets database info through AJAX

for (i = 0; i < tblData.Rows.Count; i++) {
    // some code to append table element
    verifyData(strStartDate, ..., strTotalHours, i);
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is what the original author was going for but was not sure how it would effect re-usability.